# How do I print the list in a list by searching for a specific keyword?

Tags: python, list

I want to write a python function which will print the list in list by searching for a specific keyword. This is my function but it doesn't work.

```
user_adresses = [["John","Walker","New York","10001"],["Larry","Smith","Denver","80123"]]

def search(user_adresses):

    alpha = str(input("What are you searching for? "))


    for item in user_adresses:

        print(str(item[0:])[1:-1])
```

The program will ask me what I am searching for, if I type "John" it should only print the list with John -> "John","Walker","New York","10001"

But in this way it will me print me all lists. What should be added to the function to print just the list with the specific keyword in it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can check for membership in a list using `in`. This will match any and all full words that are in the user address.

```
for user in user_adresses:
    if alpha in user:
        print(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user_adresses = [["John","Walker","New York","10001"],["Larry","Smith","Denver","80123"]]

def search(user_adresses):
    alpha = str(input("What are you searching for? "))

    for item in user_adresses:
        if alpha in item:
            print(item)
```

Use `in` operator to check if the input is in a given item

Answer (score 0):

You can express this quite concisely:

```
for match in (address in user_addresses if alpha in address):
    print(match)
```

This will print every match, where a 'match' is any 'address' in `user_addresses` if the term `alpha` occurs in `address`.

Answer (score 0):

This peace of code should work.
Consider to use dictionary instead of list.

```
def search(user_addresses):
    alpha = input("What are you searching for? ")
    for user_address in user_addresses:
        if alpha in user_address:
            print(user_address)
```